# Can anyone tell me how to disable the href link in this code without losing the embed capability on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the embed code that was generated by the countdown timer widget:

```
<div class="tc_div_41086" style="width:650px;height:162.50px;border:1px solid #C0C0C0">
    <a title="Countdown to North Texas Giving Day" href="http://www.tickcounter.com/widget/countdown/1474527600000/america-chicago/dhms/FFFFFF76BD1D000000FF0000/650/C0C0C01/Countdown_to_North_Texas_Giving_Day">Countdown to North Texas Giving Day</a>
    <a title="Countdown" href="http://www.tickcounter.com/">Countdown</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = "http://www.tickcounter.com/loader.js";
    s.async = 'async';
    s.onload = function() {
      tc_widget_loader('tc_div_41086', 'Countdown', 650, ["1474520400000", "america-chicago", "dhms", "FFFFFF76BD1D000000FF0000", "650", "C0C0C01", "Countdown to North Texas Giving Day"]);
    };
    s.onreadystatechange = s.onload;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(s);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: Please format your HTML more readably. It's impossible to understand with everything on one line like that.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you even mean? What are you embedding? Have you tried just removing the links or whatever it is you want to remove?

Comment: What's your question? Please put a detailed question in the text, the title should just be a brief summary.

Comment: I don't think you can remove the `href`. The code in `tc_widget_loader` searches for  an `iframe` that contains `href` that contains links to `www.tickcounter.com`.

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
.tc_div_41086{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```